# AWS QuickSight new api operations recently announced not available in the CLI 1.16.200

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

I found the following blog about the new api operations available for quick sight:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/evolve-your-analytics-with-amazon-quicksights-new-apis-and-theming-capabilities/

After upgrading to the last cli version the new commands are not available:

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.200 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.190

aws quicksight create-data-source --generate-cli-skeleton > create-data-source-cli-input.json
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

create-group                             | create-group-membership
delete-group                             | delete-group-membership
delete-user                              | delete-user-by-principal-id
describe-group                           | describe-user
get-dashboard-embed-url                  | list-group-memberships
list-groups                              | list-user-groups
list-users                               | register-user
update-group                             | update-user
help
```

Based on the first answer I want to clarify that I executed the following command to upgrade to the latest version: 
`pip3 install --upgrade --user awscli`, but apparently is not working I always get the following version: `aws-cli/1.16.200 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.190`

If I execute the command for a second time I got the following:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>pip3 install --upgrade --user awscli
Requirement already up-to-date: awscli in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (**1.16.296**)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: botocore==1.13.32 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from awscli) (1.13.32)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: colorama<0.4.2,>=0.2.5; python_version != "2.6" and python_version != "3.3" in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from awscli) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from awscli) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: PyYAML<5.2,>=3.10; python_version != "2.6" and python_version != "3.3" in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from awscli) (5.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: docutils<0.16,>=0.10 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from awscli) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from awscli) (3.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version >= "3.4" in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.13.32->awscli) (1.25.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.13.32->awscli) (0.9.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil<2.8.1,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7" in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.13.32->awscli) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<2.8.1,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"->botocore==1.13.32->awscli) (1.12.0)
```

The last version appears in the messages but the version remains the same:

```
c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (**1.16.296**)
```

I will try to re-install instead of perform the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The latest versions supports these new API actions. You might have attempted to upgrade before this was rolled out. You are using the aws-cli version 1.16.200 which is quite old, attempt to upgrade or install it manually with the help of [Installing the AWS CLI version 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv1.html).

Be aware that IAM does not currently list these actions as available for assignment through the online policy generator, and you will have to write these in manually in the JSON Policy Editor.

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.296 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.0.0-36-generic botocore/1.13.32
$ aws quicksight commands
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

cancel-ingestion                         | create-dashboard                        
create-data-set                          | create-data-source                      
create-group                             | create-group-membership                 
create-iam-policy-assignment             | create-ingestion                        
create-template                          | create-template-alias                   
delete-dashboard                         | delete-data-set                         
delete-data-source                       | delete-group                            
delete-group-membership                  | delete-iam-policy-assignment            
delete-template                          | delete-template-alias                   
delete-user                              | delete-user-by-principal-id             
describe-dashboard                       | describe-dashboard-permissions          
describe-data-set                        | describe-data-set-permissions           
describe-data-source                     | describe-data-source-permissions        
describe-group                           | describe-iam-policy-assignment          
describe-ingestion                       | describe-template                       
describe-template-alias                  | describe-template-permissions           
describe-user                            | get-dashboard-embed-url                 
list-dashboard-versions                  | list-dashboards                         
list-data-sets                           | list-data-sources                       
list-group-memberships                   | list-groups                             
list-iam-policy-assignments              | list-iam-policy-assignments-for-user    
list-ingestions                          | list-tags-for-resource                  
list-template-aliases                    | list-template-versions                  
list-templates                           | list-user-groups                        
list-users                               | register-user                           
tag-resource                             | untag-resource                          
update-dashboard                         | update-dashboard-permissions            
update-dashboard-published-version       | update-data-set                         
update-data-set-permissions              | update-data-source                      
update-data-source-permissions           | update-group                            
update-iam-policy-assignment             | update-template                         
update-template-alias                    | update-template-permissions             
update-user                              | help
```

Comment: Thanks Haakon, I ran the command to upgrade but is not working I will try reinstalling instead of just upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the CLI was installed using the MSI windows installer but the upgrade was performed using pip. Removing the CLI and reinstalling with pip3 solved the issue.